PowerShell Process files in parallel - Error
I'm having an issue with the code below and cannot figure out why I'm missing something. Could someone help me out? I've also included the error, I am using PowerShell v7.
The code basically should scan a directory and all sub directories for PII data in those file formats. Ideally output the full file path of the items with PII data.
Thanks
ERROR:
Line |
 109 |      $results = $files | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
     |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be
     | used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.

CODE:
# Import necessary modules
Import-Module ImportExcel -ErrorAction Stop
# Import-Module PSWord -ErrorAction Stop
# Import-Module PSWriteWord -ErrorAction Stop
# Import-Module PdfTools -ErrorAction Stop

# Define PII patterns
$patterns = @{
    "Email" = "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b"
    "Phone" = "\b\d{3}[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4}\b"
    "SSN"   = "\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b"
    "CreditCard" = "\b(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})\b"
}

# Define file types and search paths
$fileTypes = ".txt", ".csv", ".xlsx", ".docx", ".pdf"
$searchPaths = @(
    "E:\Documents"
)

function Search-PIIInFile {
    param (
        [string]$filePath,
        [hashtable]$patterns
    )

    $results = @()
    $fileExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filePath).ToLower()
    $content = ""

    # Open and read file based on type
    switch ($fileExtension) {
        ".txt" {
            $content = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        ".csv" {
            $content = Import-Csv -Path $filePath | Out-String
        }
        ".xlsx" {
            $headerNames = 1..100 | ForEach-Object { "Column$_" }
            $content = Import-Excel -Path $filePath -HeaderName $headerNames | Out-String
        }
        ".docx" {
            $doc = Get-WordText -FilePath $filePath
            $content = $doc | Out-String
        }
        ".pdf" {
            $content = Get-PdfText -Path $filePath -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        default {
            Write-Warning "Unsupported file type: $fileExtension for file $filePath"
            return
        }
    }

    # Safe output handling for content
    if ($null -eq $content -or $content.Length -eq 0) {
        Write-Output "No content was retrieved from $filePath."
    } else {
        Write-Output "Content length from ${filePath}: $($content.Length)"
        Write-Output "Snippet of content from ${filePath}: $($content.Substring(0, [Math]::Min(200, $content.Length)))"
    }

    # Search for patterns
    foreach ($patternName in $patterns.Keys) {
        $pattern = $patterns[$patternName]
        if ($content -match $pattern) {
            $matches = [regex]::matches($content, $pattern)
            foreach ($match in $matches) {
                $lineNum = ($content -split "`r?`n").IndexOf($match.Value) + 1
                $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    File       = $filePath
                    PII_Type   = $patternName
                    Match      = $match.Value
                    LineNumber = if ($lineNum -gt 0) { $lineNum } else { "N/A" }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $results
}

$logPath = "C:\Logs\PII_Search_Results.log"

# Collect all files and search for PII across multiple directories
$allResults = @()

foreach ($searchPath in $searchPaths) {
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $searchPath)) {
        Write-Output "Path does not exist: $searchPath"
        continue
    }
    
    Write-Output "Searching in path: $searchPath"

    # Get all files in the search path with specified types
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchPath -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {
        $fileTypes -contains $_.Extension.ToLower()
    }

    # Ensure that we have files to process
    if ($files.Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Output "No files found in path: $searchPath"
        continue
    }

    # Process files in parallel
    $results = $files | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        $FilePath = $using:_.FullName
        $Patterns = $using:_.Patterns # <= unclear where is `$Patterns` defined outside this context

        try {
            # Call the search function and return results
            return Search-PIIInFile -filePath $FilePath -patterns $Patterns
        }
        catch {
        Write-Output "Error processing file ${FilePath}: $_"
        }
    } 
    
    # Aggregate results from parallel processing
    $allResults += $results
}

# Output results to a .txt file
$txtPath = "C:\Logs\PII_Search_Results.txt"
$allResults | ForEach-Object {
    "$($_.File) - PII Type: $($_.PII_Type) - Match: $($_.Match) - Line Number: $($_.LineNumber)"
} | Out-File -FilePath $txtPath -Encoding UTF8

Write-Output "PII search completed. Results saved to $txtPath."

Thanks for looking, hope the entire code helps with the figuring out what I've gotten wrong.

-ArgumentList is available only in the PropertyAndMethodSet Parameter Set:
(Get-Command ForEach-Object).Parameters['ArgumentList'].ParameterSets

# Key                  Value
# ---                  -----
# PropertyAndMethodSet System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata

And -Parallel is available only in the ParallelParameterSet Parameter Set:
(Get-Command ForEach-Object).Parameters['Parallel'].ParameterSets

# Key                  Value
# ---                  -----
# ParallelParameterSet System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata

That's why you're getting this error, -Parallel and -ArgumentList cannot be used together due to not being in a same Parameter Set. You can read about_Parameter_Sets for more details.
To fix your code you can get the local variables using the $using: scope modifier and removing -ArgumentList. Another consideration is that unless your Search-PIIInFile is defined in a Module that can be discovered thru $env:PSModulePath, you will most likely need to pass-in the definition of this function to the parallel scope (see code with comments).
# store the function definition outside the parallel scope
$functionDefinition = ${function:Search-PIIInFile}.ToString()

$results = $files | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $FilePath = $using:_.FullName
    $Patterns = $using:Patterns
    # pass-in the function definition and define the function in this scope
    ${function:Search-PIIInFile} = $using:functionDefinition

    try {
        # Call the search function and return results
        return Search-PIIInFile -filePath $FilePath -patterns $Patterns
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "Error processing file ${FilePath}: $_"
    }
}


Thank you for the updated code! So the Patterns comes from a function I have which is different types of PII data, I'll add that to the original post.

@nutt318 got it, you will also probably have issues running Search-PIIInFile in the parallel context, you will need to pass-in this function to the parallel scope, I'll add that to my answer too

Great, thank you! I'm guessing I'll have a lot of other problems then. I'll post the entire code that I currently have. I probably should have started over but I tried to add searching .xlsx, docx, pdfs into my PII scan and made it multi threaded to run faster with the parallel.
Looks like I'm a little over my head on the parallel. Thanks again for helping, full code posted now.

@nutt318 looking at the last edit you will also need to take the same approach for functions such as Get-WordText and Get-PdfText unless those are from a module. Working with multithreading in pwsh is complex, the parallel scope can't see what is defined in the execution context of the caller. I will not keep editing my answer as there is too much code to go thru and this is going off on a tangent from original asked question, but I hope this is clear and understood.

I'll try my best, thanks for the help and how the parallel scope works!
